# How to prove that during loading session of glass container, which will happen first - overstressing or buckling - via FEA?

Tags: structural-engineering, finite-element-method, ansys

How do I prove that during a loading session of a glass container, between two failure modes, overstressing or buckling, which will happen first via FEA? Is there any scientific way of approaching this problem? Possible references will also be appreciated.

Comment: A finite element model doesn't know anything about "overstressing" or "crushing." You have to *interpret* the results of the model using (measured) material properties for the glass. It's not clear what you are really asking here.

Comment: yes I am aware of the fact that an FE model doesn't know about overstressing or crushing, I wanted to know how do I interpret the results of the model so that I can show that the container will overstress first and then fail. How should I approach this?

Comment: Welcome to Engineering Stack Exchange @raihannirvik!  I have edited your question to be more in line with the useage guidelines of the Engineering Stack Exchange Site.  Please review the guidelines and my edit and ensure that nothing was said that changed your original intent.  If needed, you can revert the edit.

Comment: You run various FEA scenarios and pick the worst Safety Factor.

Answer (score 1):

Many Finite Element programs (such as ANSYS) will comes with several modes for their model.  ANSYS comes with a buckling mode as well as a normal stress mode.  Simply run the same model in both modes and review.  You should find that your answers will tell you the maximum stress (for the stress model) and the maximum load for the buckling.  Then you can run factors of safety on both modes.  Bear in mind that buckling in FEA is ***highly*** sensitive to flaws, smaller than can usually be detected.  As such, the results are almost always taken to be about 80% lower for most models and it is suggested that a scale model be built and crushed in a test lab to ensure accuracy.